# How to call parent function in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I checked quite a lot of examples but found most of them having events fired in Child Component.
Can someone please suggest how can I call the Parent Component's function in child with the click event on Parent Component? Thanks.

Parent Component (`app.js`):

```
Class App extends Component { 

    handleClick = (e, id, text) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({val: text})
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Form val={this.state.val} Click={this.handleClick.bind(this) }/>
            <Button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, todo.id, todo.text)}>
               <Icon>edit_icon</Icon>
            </Button>
        </div>
      )
   }
 }
```

Child Component (`form.js`):

```
    this.props.Click(); //where should i call this function since my button is in parent component

Class Form extends Component{

    render() {
        const { text } = this.state;
        return (
          <TextField
              value={text}
              color="secondary"
          />
        )
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand, your function is in Parent, your button is in Parent, why you try to invoke it in child? Usually people facing such similar problem is when button in child and function in parent, in that case at least making sense in terms of design

Comment: Because my form is in child component.

Comment: i think it is not a good design,its good to have button in the child component

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call it in your Child component, you need an event to trigger it or maybe a condition. So, for example in your `form.js`, we will trigger it with a button click form your child component

```
render() {
    const { text } = this.state;
    return (
      <TextField
          value={text}
          color="secondary"
      />
      <Button onClick={this.props.Click} />
    )
  }
}
```

Maybe, using a Button in your child component is not a great choice for your case since you already have a Button to call the Click function in your parent component, this Button in child component I made is only for example

Comment: I know this way it would work but i don't have any button in the child component, i simply want to pass the text value to child component with the click event on Parent Component.

Comment: @JasonWilliam Try this in your `form.js`, `<TextField value={this.props.val} color="secondary" />`, and trigger the changes from you parent's button

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is use a ref to call the function..

```
// create the ref
constructor() {
  super();
  this.myFormRef = React.createRef()
}

// click handler for the button
handleClick  = (e, id, text) => {
  // here you have the child instance which gives you access to its functions
  this.myFormRef.someChildMethodThatIsOnTheChildClass()
}
render() {
  // notice here we use the ref on the form via... ref={this.myFormRef}
  return (
    <Form val={this.state.val} ref={this.myFormRef} Click={this.handleClick.bind(this) }/>
    <Button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, todo.id, todo.text)}>
       <Icon>edit_icon</Icon>
    </Button>
  )
)
```

I would like to note though that it doesn't seem to make much sense as to why you want to do this. You should probably re-think your architecture. Also what is the button press supposed to be doing? submitting the form?